# Subdomains using PHP on Shared Apache Server Hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I require help to create subdomains on a PHP only install, not WordPress:

- Dynamic using CNAME
- Wildcard
- Programmatically

My website currently resolves at the TLD URL and is not seemingly reliant on the .HTACCESS file.

The root files are being served or resolving at the main domain URL AND the subdomain URL(??!!), again without an .HTACCESS file in the subdomain folder nor .HTACCESS having any control on/in the subdomain folder.

I am a noob to PHP in all honesty....

I am trying to display multiple subdomains and assume, possibly, that I need to do the following

- Activate wildcard subdomains on the server for HTACCESS 
  or
- Set up subdomains dynamically possibly using CNAME (Canonical).

I am here to learn from The PHP Masters

Thanks in advance

P. S. WordPress works through my host server using 1click install using .HTACCESS

Comment: PHP, the language and knowledge of thereof, has nothing to do with how Domain Name System works and PHP has nothing to do with how your web server handles requests.

Comment: @N.B. So the answer lies purely with HTACCESS, possibly server settings and DNS.... In order to correctly display subdomains, using a PHP (non WordPress website)